# Is there any sites where users share custom PHP code?

Tags: php, resources

Do you know of any websites that allow users to share there custom PHP functions and code snippets  other then?  It would be nice to compile a list of a few good resources

http://www.phpclasses.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Snipplr.com - A public source code repository for sharing code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Might be obvious to some, but don't forget to include http://pear.php.net/ in your list. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day when I built some PHP3 sites,
PHP Builder was the place to go. They are still live, but URL shows a number instead of domain name :)

http://63.236.73.209/snippet/

Answer (score 0):

[Hot Scripts](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/) is one of the biggest sites to my knowledge. There is commercial and free code (easily sortable).

<sub>And you should probably make this Community Wiki.</sub>